# Probability of getting N distinct types of objects in r tries from a set of N distinct objects

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Given N distinct objects that have an equal chance of being drawn (with replacement), what is the probability that X draws are needed to get all N types.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  consider the chance you get less than $N$ and subtract from $1$.  You need to use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  If you search the site for that you will find many examples.  For $r \lt N$ it is rather easy.

Answer (score 0):

The probability is:
$$
P_X=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-k-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{X-1}.
$$